# How to allow anonymous users to use a certain form? - Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to allow anonymous users into a certain form so they can register some data. Is it possible to do it? How can I approach it?

What I am doing is extending the mass mailing module to send emails to a certain kind of contacts specific to my organization. I created a form in which I can register the contact information (ex: name, email, topics in which contact is interested). What I need is that an unauthenticated user can fill this form with his information so newsletters can be send to him. I have tried setting the model permissions to the base.group_public but I still get the login form.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How do you build the form? How do you only allow anonymous users? What have you tried?

Comment: What I am doing is extending the mass mailing module to send emails to a certain kind of contacts specific to my organization. I created a form in which I can register the contact information (ex: name, email, topics in which contact is interested). What I need is that an unauthenticated user can fill this form with his information so newsletters can be send to him. I have tried setting the model permissions to the base.group_public but I still get the login form. Do I make myself clear now?

Comment: Just share the view with portal access. so the mail recipients can view the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I followed this procedure to make this work.

1. I intalled the website module as well as the Portal module.
2. I created a template inheriting the website layout (This creates a 'public form').
3. I created a controller that creates a model with the parameters from the template.

The code for the template is:

```
<template id="register">
<t t-call="iica_contacts.layout">
  <t t-set="title">Register</t>
  <link href="/iica_contacts/static/libraries/js/multi_select/css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <form action="/contact/register" method="post" data-model_name="iica_contacts.contact" id="registration-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="request.csrf_token()"/>
    <div class="container margin-top-20">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 form-group o_website_form_required_custom">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Full name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" data-validation="required" t-att-value="name or contact.name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Contact information</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group o_website_form_required_custom">
                    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" data-validation="required,email" t-att-value="email or contact.email" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone number:</label>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" t-att-value="phone or contact.phone" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group o_website_form_required_custom">
                    <label class="control-label" for="language">Language:</label>
                    <select name="language" class="form-control" data-validation="required">
                      <option value=""> -- Select language -- </option>
                      <option value="1" t-att-selected="1 == language">Spanish</option>
                      <option value="2" t-att-selected="2 == language">English</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">Location information</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group o_website_form_required_custom">
                    <label class="control-label" for="country_id">Country:</label>
                    <select name="country_id" class="form-control" data-validation="required">
                      <option value=""> -- Select country -- </option>
                      <t t-foreach="countries" t-as="country">
                        <option t-att-value="country.id" t-att-selected="country.id == contact.country_id.id">
                          <t t-esc="country.name" />
                        </option>
                      </t>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="company">Company:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" t-att-value="company or contact.company" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="sector">Sector:</label>
                    <select name="sector" class="form-control">
                      <option value=""> -- Select sector -- </option>
                      <option value="1" t-att-selected="1 == sector">Public</option>
                      <option value="2" t-att-selected="2 == sector">Private</option>
                      <option value="3" t-att-selected="3 == sector">ONG</option>
                      <option value="4" t-att-selected="4 == sector">International Organization</option>
                      <option value="5" t-att-selected="5 == sector">Financial</option>
                      <option value="6" t-att-selected="6 == sector">Other</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
              <li class="active"><a href="#products-interest" data-toggle="tab">Products of interest</a></li>
              <li><a href="#areas-interest" data-toggle="tab">Areas of interest</a></li>
              <li><a href="#topics-interest" data-toggle="tab">Topics of interest</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div id="products-interest" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>Products of interest</h3>
                <select name="products_interest" multiple="multiple" class="form-control elegant-multi-select">
                  <t t-foreach="products_interest" t-as="product">
                    <option t-att-value="product.id">
                      <t t-esc="product.name" />
                    </option>
                  </t>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div id="areas-interest" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Areas of interest</h3>
                <select name="areas_interest" multiple="multiple" class="form-control elegant-multi-select">
                  <t t-foreach="areas_interest" t-as="area">
                    <option t-att-value="area.id">
                      <t t-esc="area.name" />
                    </option>
                  </t>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div id="topics-interest" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Topics of interest</h3>
                <select name="topics_interest" multiple="multiple" class="form-control elegant-multi-select">
                  <t t-foreach="topics_interest" t-as="topic">
                    <option t-att-value="topic.id">
                      <t t-esc="topic.name" />
                    </option>
                  </t>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default azuliica hover-azuliica2 lt-blanco margin-top-10">
              Register <span class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="/iica_contacts/static/libraries/js/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/iica_contacts/static/libraries/js/node_modules/jquery-form-validator/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/iica_contacts/static/libraries/js/multi_select/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
  <script src="/iica_contacts/static/src/js/registration.js"></script>
  <script>
    $.validate();
    loadMultiSelect('.elegant-multi-select');
  </script>
</t>
```

The code for the controller:

```
class IICAContactsController(http.Controller):
@http.route('/contact/register', type='http', auth='public', website='true')
def register(self, redirect=None, **post):
    countries = request.env['res.country'].sudo().search([])
    values = {
        'countries' : countries,
    }

    if post:
        error_message, valid = self._validate_form(post)
        if valid == 1:
            self._process_registration(post)
            return request.redirect('/contact/register/success')
        else:
            return request.redirect('/contact/register/error')
    else:
        contact = request.env['iica_contacts.contact']
        values.update({
            'contact' : contact,
        })

    return request.render("iica_contacts.register", values)
```